# Diffrent partial derivative

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How to find point's where mixed partial derivate are diffrent .
I have x*y defined in a domain and i want to find the point's where the schwarz or young theorem does not work

Comment: For starters, you must look at points in which the function is not of class $C^2$.

Comment: I already found this point but how to proof that they are diffrent